# Identify series/tv film with hologram tv and eye gouging

Tags: tv, story-identification

I believe it was a series or maybe a film set in present or near future.
I remember that one character invented a true 3d holographic TV. At the demonstration he was seemingly murdered by a (samurai?/ninja?) assassin, who was later revealed as a hologram.
Another thing I remember, is that a (I think blind) character gouges the eyes of another character (possibly one who blinded him).

I most definitely saw it in the 1990s.

Wikipedia's [list of holograms in fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography#Holography_in_fiction) returns nothing, tvtropes likewise (including the eyescream subpage)

this has been bugging me for ages...

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I am a messy writer when I have little time:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

searching the internet sure can lead you to strange places. and when I saw a picture of a woman with a strange palm tattoo on her back a strange deja vu came over me. so I went digging a bit and found this: [WILD PALMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Palms)

it is most definitely what I was looking for.